# utf-8 encoded XML text in ElementTree Python3

Tags: xml, utf-8, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have a bytes object containing a utf-8 encoded xml file(say, file1). I need to save this file to directory as an xml file so I convert it into an ElementTree with the following code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(file1))
```

I expect when I convert this back using the following line to also be utf-8 encoded and to be entirely equal to file1.

```
file2 = ET.tostring(tree.getroot(), encoding='utf-8', method='xml')
```

To be clear, I expect file1 == file2 to return True, yet it returns False. Looking at the bytes objects, I can see that file1 starts with the following line yet this line is missing in file2.

```
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> #file1
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: If you just want to write the bytes to disk, there's no need to parse the structure, just open a file in binary mode and `.write()` the bytes object. – The differences might come from minor serialisation differences, eg. from the order of the attributes. For example, `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` is equivalent to `<?xml encoding="UTF-8" version="1.0"?>` in terms of XML, but it's not the same string.

Comment: Oh, just realised you're missing the XML declaration. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12966488) about how you can preserve it.

Comment: @lenz: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and `<?xml encoding="UTF-8" version="1.0"?>` are not eqivalent. The latter form is invalid. `version="1.0"` must always come first, followed by `encoding="..."`.

Comment: Thanks @mzjn, I didn't know the XML declaration was special in this respect. In regular tags the order of the attributes is irrelevant.