# Checking if XML declaration is present

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xml-declaration

I am trying to check whether an xml file contains the necessary xml declaration ("header"), let's say:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...rest of xml file...
```

I am using xml ElementTree for reading and getting info out of the file, but it seems to load a file just fine even if it does not have the header.

What I tried so far is this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(someXmlFile)    

try:
    xmlFile = ET.tostring(tree.getroot(), encoding='utf8').decode('utf8')
except:
    sys.stderr.write("Wrong xml2 header\n")
    exit(31)

if re.match(r"^\s*<\?xml version=\'1\.0\' encoding=\'utf8\'\?>\s+", xmlFile) is None:
    sys.stderr.write("Wrong xml1 header\n")
    exit(31)
```

But  the ET.tostring() function just "makes up" a header if it is not present in the file.

Is there any way to check for a xml header with ET? Or somehow throw an error while loading the file with ET.parse, if a file does not contain the xml header?

Comment: It is good practice to include an XML declaration in XML documents, but it is not a strict requirement. It says "SHOULD" here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd

Comment: Hi Dennis: have you seen my answer? Is that a working solution for you? If not are you still interested to get suggestions/answers? Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
def has_xml_declaration(xml):
    return parseString(xml).version
```

From [Wikipedia's XML declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML#XML_declaration)

> If an XML document lacks encoding specification, an XML parser assumes
>   that the encoding is UTF-8 or UTF-16, unless the encoding has already
>   been determined by a higher protocol.

...

> The declaration may be optionally omitted because it declares as its
>   encoding the default encoding. However, if the document instead makes
>   use of XML 1.1 or another character encoding, a declaration is
>   necessary. Internet Explorer prior to version 7 enters quirks mode, if
>   it encounters an XML declaration in a document served as text/html

So even if the XML declaration is omitted in an XML document, the code-snippet:

```
if re.match(r"^<\?xml\s*version=\'1\.0\' encoding=\'utf8\'\s*\?>", xmlFile.decode('utf-8')) is None:
```

will find "the" default XML declaration in this XML document. Please note, that I have used xmlFile.decode('utf-8') instead of xmlFile.
If you don't worry to use `minidom`, you can use the following code-snippet:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

dom = parse('bookstore-003.xml')
print('<?xml version="{}" encoding="{}"?>'.format(dom.version, dom.encoding))
```

Here is a working [fiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/be051090-4466-4856-ab78-a9f41f8679e6/?i=true)
Int bookstore-001.xml an XML declaration ist present, in bookstore-002.xml no XML declaration ist present and in bookstore-003.xml a different XML declaration than in the first example ist present. The `print` instruction prints accordingly the version and the encoding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?xml version="None" encoding="None"?>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

Comment: Here's where the two fields get [set](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Lib/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py#L441-L449).